# why this goes in cycle

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, cycle

I faced interesting problem. Everything works well at first click on my partial view submit. it goes in db and saves my records. but if i'll click second time it (when first click will end his job) it goes twice and saves everything twice. **at next click previous * 2**.  Anyone can explain what's going on?

It's facebook application but i dont think that it's fb problem

my controller is:

```
KubetiDbContext db = new KubetiDbContext();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string request = Session["signed_request"].ToString();
        FaceBook client = new FaceBook();
        FBuserinfo user = new FBuserinfo();
        SignedRequest sr = client.parseSignedRequest(request);

        var db_user = (from a in db.Users
                       where a.fbId == sr.user_id
                       select a).FirstOrDefault();

        ViewBag.ID = db_user.id;


        //var participants = from q in db.fifthWeekBids
        var laptop = (from a in db.Laptops
                      select a).FirstOrDefault();

        ViewBag.countLeft = laptop.countLeft;

        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Bet()
    {
        var laptop = (from a in db.Laptops
                      select a).FirstOrDefault();

        ViewBag.startPrice = laptop.startPrice;
        return YourPlace();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Bet(string code)
    {
        string request = Session["signed_request"].ToString();
        FaceBook client = new FaceBook();
        FBuserinfo user = new FBuserinfo();
        SignedRequest sr = client.parseSignedRequest(request);

        var db_user = (from a in db.Users
                       where a.fbId == sr.user_id
                       select a).FirstOrDefault();

        using (KubetiDbContext _db = new KubetiDbContext())
        {
            firstWeekBid fw = new firstWeekBid();
            fw.userId = db_user.id;
            fw.bidCount = int.Parse(code);
            fw.dateOfBid = DateTime.Now;
            _db.firstWeekBids.Add(fw);
            _db.SaveChanges();
        }


        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            if (ViewData["IsAjax"] == null || (bool)ViewData["IsAjax"] != false)
            {
                ViewData["IsAjax"] = true;
            }
            return Bet();
        }

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult YourPlace()
    {

        return View();
    }
```

view:

```
<div class="bigBgPaper">
<div id="regLogo"></div>
<div id="regAucHead"></div>
<div id="rightRed">

</div>

<nav class="mainNav">
    @Html.ActionLink("ჩემი პროფილი", "Index", "Profile")
    <div class="smallKub"></div>
    @Html.ActionLink("პრიზები", "Index", "Prizes")
    <div class="smallKub"></div>
    @Html.ActionLink("აუქციონი", "Index", "Auction", null, new { @style = "color:red;" })
    <div class="smallKub"></div>
    @Html.ActionLink("გამარჯვებულები", "Index", "Winners")
</nav>

<div class="auqcPrize">
    <div class="prizeOverflow">
        <div class="prizePic"></div>
        <div class="prizeLeft"><p>@ViewBag.countLeft</p></div>
    </div>
    <span>Lenovo</span>
    <br />
    <span>IdeaPad G50-30</span>
    <br />
    <span>CPU: 2160</span>
    <br />
    <span>RAM: 2GB</span>
</div>
<div id="monaw">
    <span>მონაწილეები</span>
    <div id="monawline"></div>
</div>
<div id="cowndtdownDIv">
    <span>დასრულებამდე</span>
    <div id="timer"></div>
</div>

<div id="betdiv">
    @Html.Partial("Bet")
</div>
```

and partial view:

```
@model Kubeti.Models.Codes

@if (ViewData["IsAjax"] != null && (bool)ViewData["IsAjax"] == true)
{
   ViewData["IsAjax"] = false;
}
else
{
<span>შეიყვანეთ თქვენი ფსონი</span>

using (Ajax.BeginForm("Bet", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "pozition", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.code)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.code)

    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
<span id="minBet">დასადები ფსონის მინიმალური რაოდენობა: @ViewBag.startPrice</span>
<span id="pozition">თქვენი პოზიცია: </span>
```

}

Comment: hmm. does your Bet partial get replicated? I can see the ajax form replaces the context of the position element, but this is outside the form

Answer (score 1):

You have the `Ajax.BeginForm` inside the Partial View.
This will cause that per each call, the form submits and the controller outputs another form that will nest inside the parent form.

This will cause a weird behavior on your html, by submitting every form you have enclosing your submit button.